# PHP Doc - How to specify the exact abstract type?

Tags: php, interface, phpstorm, abstract, phpdoc

Imagine following abstract Interface

```
interface IDomainRepository {
    /**
     * Finds a Domain Object by the Id
     *
     * @param int $id the id of the object
     *
     * @return IDomainObject the domain object
     */
    public function findById($id);

    //More than that method...
}
```

And now a specific Interface which extends from IDomainRepository

```
interface IUserRepository extends IDomainRepository {
    //More than only extending...
}
```

If i call something like this, i want type hint without extra comment here (because i use this very often).

```
function foo(IUserRepository $repo) {
    $user = $repo->findById(42)
    //Typehint User without @var User $user
}
```

Currently i do it this way:

```
/**
 * Interface IUserRepository
 * @method User findById($id)
 */
interface IUserRepository extends  {
}
```

But the "@method" parameter is for hidden magic methods. So this feels wrong. Is  there a better solution availible?

Should i don't have a Base Interface, only the specific one (Which means copy & pasting about 20 Method Signatures?

Comment: This would seem to be a limitation of the IDE's hierarchy parsing and indexing when its generates its object model.  The base inheritence in the code should be enough to give you the autocompletion you're looking for.  Using `@method` is indeed only a hack to trick the IDE into the behavior you need.  There is not a "better" or "proper" way to do it... the IDE is what's failing you here, IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As there is no return type hinting in PHP yet it's most times all about preferences, depending on the IDE used there may be no difference in using an `@method` tag or a docblock for an additional method declaration, so....

Note that you don't necessarily have to *move* the methods (and you most probably don't want to anyways as it would make implementations of `IDomainRepository` not require a `findById()` method), but you can simply redeclare/overwrite them in your extending interfaces when necessary and supply a proper docblock as shown by @Deele:

```
interface IUserRepository extends IDomainRepository {
    /**
     * Finds a User by Id
     *
     * @param int $id the id of the object
     *
     * @return IUserRepository the User object
     */
    public function findById($id);
}
```

Personally I would consider that the cleaner approach over using `@method`, as it makes it more clear how a concrete implementation of `findById()` should behave (by just looking at the code of the method declaration), and that it is expected to be different to the one of the base interface.

On a side note, one day this might also be "compatible" to the covariant return-type hinting proposed in [**PHP RFC: Return Type Declarations**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/returntypehinting):

```
// Covariant return-type:

interface Collection {
    function map(callable $fn): Collection;
}

interface Set extends Collection {
    function map(callable $fn): Set;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no way to do that because such depth is not built-in in PHPDoc code.

Only way I can think of, to save lines would be to repeat that same `findById()` method inside your `User` class and make it just call parent method `findById()` and add a comment with modified `@return` like this

```
interface IUserRepository extends IDomainRepository {

    /**
     * @see IDomainRepository::findById()
     *
     * @param int $id the id of the object
     *
     * @return IUserRepository the User object
     */
    public function findById($id) {
        return parent::findById($id);
    }
}
```

PS: `findById()` by my understanding of OOP logic should be static function.

Comment: The reason, it is non static is `__construct(IUserRepository $userRepository)` from Domain Driven Design. Have i unterstood something wrong? Your provided code will not work (It is an Interface, no abstract class), but tells me, i should maybe move the `findBy*` methods in the final interface instead of the base interface? Not sure if it is better then the `@method User findById($id)` notation, since php doc will not be executed instead of php code. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem, maybe `static` or `$this` as return type might be something for you.

The idea behind refers to [Late Static Bindings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php)

```
interface IDomainRepository
{
    /**
     * @param int $id the id of the object
     *
     * @return static the domain object
     */
    public function findById($id);
}


interface IUserRepository extends IDomainRepository
{
    /**
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return static
     */
    public function findUserByName($name);
}


function foo(IUserRepository $repo)
{
    $user = $repo->findById(42);
    $user->find... // suggestions by PHPStorm: findById and findUserByName
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I am trying to get `$user` Type Hinted as `User` , not as `UserRepository`, which is already given via parameter.

Comment: So something like Generic `IUserRepository extends IDomainRepository<User>` in other languages